# libGDX loading all images from directory into AssetManager in loop taking ages

Tags: java, libgdx

I have, up till now been loading all textures into my AssetManager class by -

```
manager.load("images/image_1.png", Texture.class);
```

this has been working perfectly but I am working on a project that uses a very large number of small images and would like to use a more generic way of loading these files. I have tried -

```
FileHandle[] fileArray = Gdx.files.internal("images").list();
    for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++){
        //if it is not a directory
        if(!(fileArray[i].isDirectory())){
                String stringPath = fileArray[i].path();
            //load file
                manager.load(stringPath, Texture.class);
        }
    }
```

this works but it takes a long time compared to the previous method. first of all why? is the time its taking due to obtaining a list of FileHandle instances? and secondly, is there a way to load all images from a directory into the Asset manager as Textures that will not take this long?

Comment: "a project that uses a very large number of small images" --> Use a `TextureAtlas`!

Comment: @noone this should be an answer^^ Perfect solution! It will also reduce the `Texture` bindings as far as i know so it will increase performance.

Comment: @noone thanks, ill do that. ive never used an atlas before hence why it didnt cross my mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To not leave this question unanswered:

In case you have a lot of different images, you should use a [`TextureAtlas`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas.html). To create those, you can either use it directly from code (see [this wiki article](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Texture-packer)), or use [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-texturepacker-gui/) (a bit outdated) GUI.

Using an atlas will solve many problems at once.

1. It will decrease the loading time.
2. It will solve the problem of being forced to have textures of a size with a power of two (POT). An atlas will usually be of a valid size by default.
3. Since you pack several images at once into one big texture, the size in total becomes smaller (less memory consumption), because you only have to extend a single image to POT size, instead of every single one.
4. The performance will increase because there are less texture bindings necessary. All you do is draw different parts of the same texture.